# Anchor Links In Fixed Footer of jQuery Mobile Is Not Firing An Event - Faced this in Android Devices

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I was creating an application with fixed header and footer using jquery mobile.

I placed anchor links in fixed footer, in one of my page there is a big form which has got more buttons and select drop-downs.

When user clicks on an anchor link in footer, if there is any component behind that link - that is firing instead of this event.

As per my understanding this would might be because of low `z-index` value.

---

**Updated with more information:**

**1 -** I have a fixed footer with data-position="fixed". In that, I have four links where it helps user to navigate through the application.

**2 -** The links which are present in Footer works fine when there is a plain page with some text.

**3 -** I have a scenario like, when user is on complex form, if we have a situation like when footer is upon select box/button - the links on footer is not clickable, when we user clicks on a link, the select box/button event is firing instead of footer anchor links onclick event.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class='Link1Class'><%: Html.ActionLink("Link1", "Link1Display", "Link1Data", null, htmlAttributes: new { data_icon = "Link1"})%></li>
            <li class='Link2Class'><%: Html.ActionLink("Link2", "Link1Display", "Link2Data", null, htmlAttributes: new { data_icon = "Link2"})%></li>
            <li class='Link3Class'><%: Html.ActionLink("Link3", "Link1Display", "Link3Data", null, htmlAttributes: new { data_icon = "Link3"})%></li>
            <li class='Link4Class'><%: Html.ActionLink("Link4", "Link1Display", "Link4Data", null, htmlAttributes: new { data_icon = "Link4"})%></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide more details? What is your problem? Show us some code to understand it.

Comment: Hi Borewitsch, could you please help me in this regard.

Comment: have you tried changing status of your links to disabled and then handle click with simple if else?

Comment: Hi Borewitsch, one just figured it out is that - when I change the z-index of .ui-footer-fixed to 1, it is working fine in Android and iPhone devices. But is this the best practice? .ui-footer-fixed{z-index:1 !important}